# Apply workflow failed on Websphere portal

Tags: websphere

I'm trying to apply workflow on websphere portal but I'm getting below ldap exception: http://192.168.128.38/wps/wcm/myconnect/?MOD=workflowenablement&library=TE&workflow=te.eg_templates/TE-Workflow&fix=true

`hhhh`com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.ldap.LdapConnection getDirContext CWWIM4520E  The 'javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1^@]; resolved object com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx@9c2ca1db' naming exception occurred during processing.
[6/10/18 9:14:54:754 EET] 00001145 exception     E com.ibm.ws.wim.adapter.ldap.LdapConnection getDirContext
                                 com.ibm.websphere.wim.exception.WIMSystemException: CWWIM4520E  The 'javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1\u0000]; resolved object com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx@9c2ca1db' naming exception occurred during processing.